# Setup a scalable architecture with social engine 4.7

Tags: amazon-web-services, socialengine

I am having a SocialEngine 4.7 website and want to deploy it on a clustered environment on AWS. The trouble I am facing is that social engine keeps related files locally. I am not able to find a configuration to set these things.
Ex - It keeps all the images in public/ directory. I am not sure how that is mapped.

Can someone help on how to configure a scalable social engine environment? Some pointers around this are encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like S3 is not a viable option here. Which AWS region are you deploying ? If it is not Mumbai; you can use EFS from AWS.

Comment: I am deploying in Mumbai region

Comment: LOL .. EFS is not in Mumbai..Are you going to deploy on multiple servers ? If it is single server.. then EBS can be answer. if multiple servers and u want a common directory which should be accessible by multiple servers u can evaluate Samba https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software)